# Как правильно получить список последних постов в Django?

Tags: python, django

Есть вот такой код и мне нужно сделать эту тудушку. Мне кажется должен быть какой-то способ обойти это, сделать функцию либо миксин какой-то, как это правильно будет реализовать в джанго?

```
def posts_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
    # TODO: придумать способ получения последних постов без копипаста
    last_posts = Post.objects.all()[:3]
    return render(request, 'posts/posts_list.html', context={'posts': posts, 'last_posts': last_posts})


def post_details(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
    return render(request, 'posts/post_details.html', context={'post': post})


def categories_list(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    # TODO: придумать способ получения последних постов без копипаста
    last_posts = Post.objects.all()[:3]
    return render(request, 'category/categories_list.html', context={'categories': categories, 'last_posts': last_posts})


def category_detail(request, slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
    # TODO: придумать способ получения последних постов без копипаста
    last_posts = Post.objects.all()[:3]
    return render(request, 'category/category_detail.html', context={'category': category, 'last_posts': last_posts})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После того как написал вопрос, почти сразу нашел решение.
Решение такое, с помощью **templatetags django**
Так же я использовал пакет **classytags**, что позволяет немного упрощенно писать свои теги.
Написал один тег, я его могу использовать где угодно, что решает мой вопрос с копипастом.

```
class LastPosts(Tag):
    name = 'last_posts'

    options = Options(
        'as',
        Argument('varname', required=False, resolve=False)
    )

    def render_tag(self, context, varname, name=name):
        last_posts = Post.objects.all()[:3]
        if varname:
            context[varname] = last_posts
            return ''
        else:
            context[name] = last_posts
            return ''
```